# Can a clustered index help in this scenario?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2012, sqlperformance

We have 2 tables dispense and dispensedetail.  On Dispense there is a foreign key PatientID.

Most processes and queries are in the context of a patient.
Currently the dispense table has a non-clustered index (DispenseID, PatientID).
The DispenseDetail has DispenseDetailID as primary key and a non-clustered index (DispenseID).

We are noticing some slowness that is caused by pageIo latches (sh) as sql server has to bring data from disk into memory.

I am thinking about a clustered index (DispenseID,DispenseDetailID) which can help retrieve the dispense details of a particular patient but it may worsen the insert dispense.. Dispense inserts are more important as without them there won't be data to query.

Will a non-clustered index (DispenseID,DispenseDetailID) help any?

Any comments or thoughts will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

---

Information for sqlonly

There are 4 physical CPUs each with 6 cores totalling 24 cores.  There are 32 virtual CPUs.
The database is on a VM where there are 4 physical CPUs each with 6 cores totally 24 cores.and there are 32 virtual CPUs.
The dispense table has 4000000+ rows. The dispense detail has 11000000+ rows.
I don't know how to compute or get the average page io latch wait time.  Querying sys.dm_os_latch_stats and ordering by wait time, this is the result set:

```
latch_class waiting_requests_count  wait_time_ms    max_wait_time_ms
BUFFER  62658377    97584783    12051
ACCESS_METHODS_DATASET_PARENT   950195  7870081 19652
ACCESS_METHODS_HOBT_VIRTUAL_ROOT    799403  5071290 5692
BACKUP_OPERATION    785245  372930  206
LOG_MANAGER 7   40403   11235
ACCESS_METHODS_HOBT_COUNT   7959    19728   1587
NESTING_TRANSACTION_FULL    122342  7969    59
ACCESS_METHODS_ACCESSOR_CACHE   67877   5143    65
ACCESS_METHODS_BULK_ALLOC   1644    734 49
ACCESS_METHODS_HOBT 15  76  15
SPACEMGR_ALLOCEXTENT_CACHE  169 71  10
SPACEMGR_IAM_PAGE_RANGE_CACHE   68  49  4
NESTING_TRANSACTION_READONLY    1942    11  1
SERVICE_BROKER_WAITFOR_MANAGER  31  9   4
TRACE_CONTROLLER    1   1   1
APPEND_ONLY_STORAGE_FIRST_ALLOC 11  1   1
```

In dev I used the current indexes to get just dispenseID and dispenseDetailID for the patient -- the outcome it is an index seek.  However that result set must be inserted into a temp table to get other fields and the insert to temp table is costly so the net is no improvement gained.

Thanks!

Comment: What are average PAGEIOLATCH wait times?  How many rows in each table?  How many CPU cores?

Comment: The information is in the edited message.  Thank you!

Comment: It's hard to tell what's best without deep dive in your system. A good course of action can be to do an acid test. Create the index and benchmark the results for a typical day workload. Of course we don't knows if this kind of test is possible in your environment

Comment: Jean, the acid test makes sense.  We have a dev and test environment but unfortunately do not have automation to generate the same traffic as in prod.  Our dev and test environments are also more limited than production.